# Firefox epubreader book-wide text search

Tags: firefox

[epubreader](http://www.epubread.com/en/manual.php) is a Firefox addon to read eBooks that come in `.epub` format – including a catalog view and even showing the TOC of an opened book in a separate frame.

With an `.epub` file open, you can search its contents pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> or the "<kbd>?</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>" key, which makes a search box pop up – but it looks like the search is limited to the current page. I have not been able to find a way to make [epubreader](http://www.epubread.com/en/manual.php) search the entire book for a search string.

Is there a way I am not aware to make epubreader do just that, i.e. doing a global search on the entire `.epub` file?